# Snyk disabling an automatic test

Tags: security, snyk

I'm totally surprised but I looks like it's not possible to disable Snyk automatic tests. In my case Snyk integrated with bitbucket.
Snyk analyze code each time new commit is merged.

I want to test repository once per week and this mode is set. I checked all settings and there is no option to disable new commit trigger.
Do you have any idea how to avoid it? In free plan there is limmited amount of tests so there should be an option to turn off auto testing.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution. To deactivate each new commit analysis push webhook on bitbucket site has to be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

For **automatic PR checks**, these can be disabled in the BB integration settings:

[image]

But from your description, it sounds as if it's not just scanning on every pull request, but actually on every commit.

So the question: which Bitbucket integration are you using? Bitbucket Cloud App or Bitbucket Cloud (Legacy)?